# Como inserir um objeto no doctrine, sem persistir em outras tabelas?

Tags: php, doctrine

Estou tentando inserir um registro em uma tabela que contém chave composta.
Esse é o erro:

> "A new entity was found through the relationship
>   'EnfOperEstadoBean#grupoEmpresa' that was not configured to cascade
>   persist operations for entity:
>   EnfGrupoEmpresaBean@000000000183abf100000000178339a6. To solve this
>   issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown
>   entity or configure cascade persist  this association in the mapping
>   for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot find out
>   which entity causes the problem implement
>   'EnfGrupoEmpresaBean#__toString()' to get a clue."

Pois bem, se eu colocar o `cascade={"persist"}`, ele tenta criar registro em outras tabelas. Tem alguma opção para ele não fazer nada? Eu tentei o detach para retirar os relacionamentos com outras tabelas, porém dá erro novamente.

Aos códigos...

**Insert**

```
  public function insert($grupoEmpresa, $ckDentroForaOperacao, $pcReduzBaseCalcOperacao, $ckCalculaIcms,            
    $dsObsOperacao, $vlSituTribOperacao, $operacao, $estado, $cdEnquadramentoIpi)
    {
        try{
            $this->CON->beginTransaction();

            $bean = $this->populaBean($grupoEmpresa, $ckDentroForaOperacao, $pcReduzBaseCalcOperacao, $ckCalculaIcms,            
            $dsObsOperacao, $vlSituTribOperacao, $operacao, $estado, $cdEnquadramentoIpi);

            $this->DAO->insert($this->CON,$bean);
            $this->CON->commit();
            $this->CON->flush();

        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            $this->CON->rollback();
            throw new BusinessArgusException("Problemas em inserir objeto", $ex);
        }
    }

    public function populaBean($grupoEmpresa, $ckDentroForaOperacao, $pcReduzBaseCalcOperacao, $ckCalculaIcms,            
    $dsObsOperacao, $vlSituTribOperacao, $operacao, $estado, $cdEnquadramentoIpi)
    {
        try{

//Ao inserir o persist em todos os campos que fazem relação com outras tabelas, conforme sugerido no erro, o erro muda, e vira este abaixo.

//"An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO SEASON_MIC.ENF_ESTADO (CD_ESTADO, NM_ESTADO, CD_ESTADO_IBGE, CD_TIPO_ESTADO, CK_CONTINGENCIA, CK_HORARIO_VERAO, GMT, QT_HORAS_PRAZO_CANCELAMENTO, VL_ALIQUOTA_ICMS_INTERNA, VL_PORCENTAGEM_MANDA_POBRE, VL_PORCENTAGEM_MANDA_RICO) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params {"1":"SC","2":"SANTA CATARINA","3":"42","4":"R","5":"N","6":null,"7":null,"8":24,"9":"17","10":7,"11":12}:  ORA-00001: restrição exclusiva (SEASON_MIC.PK_ENF_ESTADO


    $bean = new EnfOperEstadoBean();

    $bean->setGrupoEmpresa($this->GrupoEmpresaBO->findByPk($grupoEmpresa));

    $bean->setCkDentroForaOperacao($ckDentroForaOperacao);
    $bean->setPcReduzBaseCalcOperacao($pcReduzBaseCalcOperacao);
    $bean->setCkCalculaIcms($ckCalculaIcms);
    $bean->setDsObsOperacao($dsObsOperacao);
    $bean->setVlSituTribOperacao($vlSituTribOperacao);

    $bean->setOperacao($this->OperacaoBO->findByPk($operacao));

    $bean->setEstado($this->EstadoBO->findByPk($estado)); 

    $bean->setCdEnquadramentoIpi($cdEnquadramentoIpi);

    return $bean;

    } catch (Exception $ex) {
            throw new BusinessArgusException("Problemas ao popular o objeto", $ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente o método `$this->GrupoEmpresaBO->findByPk($grupoEmpresa)` está retornando uma empresa nova que não está persistida no banco de dados quando você tenta persistir o objeto do tipo `EnfOperEstadoBean`.

Você precisa persistir o primeiro objeto para depois persistir o segundo:

```
$grupoEmpresa = $this->GrupoEmpresaBO->findByPk($grupoEmpresa);
$bean->setGrupoEmpresa($grupoEmpresa);

$this->entityManager->persist($grupoEmpresa);
$this->entityManager->persist($bean);
$this->entityManager->flush();
```

Outra opção é retornar um objeto já persistido no método `findByPk`, mesmo que seja um novo objeto.